# Obtaining the week number in Power BI

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

I am a beginner. I’m currently building a dashboard in Power Bi. Just wondered what the best way would be to add an extra column containing the week number?

[image: Data Sample]

Comment: Check the DATEPART function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: In case it isn't clear, DATEPART is a SQL function rather than a DAX function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra column:

```
Weeknr = WEEKNUM(yourTable[date];1)
```

1 is the week starting on sunday, 2 = monday

Comment: Hi Aldert, thank you for this, this works great! The financial period is slightly different with this company, would it be possible to change week 1 of the year to start at a different date ... such as Sunday 19th January 2020

Comment: This is possible but then you need to know the rules around the 1st week exactly. E.g. Is the first week the 3rd week of the year? does this hold for all years? Or is it counted x days from the 1st of jan, starting on sunday. The calculation in DAX is possible when you know the rules.